# Floating component on the right to indicate section in the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add a floating component in my site that highlights a bullet based on scroll. Like I scroll to second section then second bullet should be highlighted.How do I do that?

[image]

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: SIte URl: http://juzzstaging.com/eha/
I am not sure how to start.

Comment: Here's a very simplistic approach - http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/kyL2e9b8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you go, I made an example of how you can do it: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/h2y33tgb/2/)

**HTML:**

```
<section>Section 1</section>
<section>Section 2</section>
<section>Section 3</section>
<section>Section 4</section>
<div id="bulletContainer">
    <div class="bullet highlighted"></div>
    <div class="bullet"></div>
    <div class="bullet"></div>
    <div class="bullet"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
section{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:400px;
    background-color:#CCC;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
#bulletContainer{
    position:fixed;
    width:25px;
    height:140px;
    left:100%;
    top:50%;
    margin-left:-50px;
    margin-top:-70px;
}
.bullet{
    background-color:#666;
    border-radius:50%;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.highlighted{
    background-color:#F90;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).on('scroll',function(){
    $('section').each(function(index){
        if($(document).scrollTop()>=$(this).offset().top-50){
            $('.bullet').not($('.bullet').eq(index)).removeClass('highlighted');
            $('.bullet').eq(index).addClass('highlighted');
        }
    });
});
$('.bullet').click(function(){
    $('.bullet').not(this).removeClass('highlighted');
    $(this).addClass('highlighted');
    var index=$(this).index();
    $('body, html').animate({scrollTop:$('section').eq(index).offset().top},200);
});
```

if you scroll the page or click on any of the bullets, you can see the bullet getting highlighted, and the page scrolling to the section.

NOTE: this code has a tolerance of `50px` it means when the scroll is **50px** above the desired element, the bullet gets highlighted, you can change it at any time.

Comment: Thanks @Amin Jafar, This is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: you're welcome, if you need any help understanding the code, just let me know

Comment: Hey @Amin Jafar, in jsfiddle when I click on the bullets the page scrolling to the section.  I used the same code in my site, but when I click on the bullets the page is not scrolling.
Site Link: http://juzzstaging.com/eha/

Comment: then you must have done something wrong! are the bullets appended dynamically?

Comment: I have just copied the code as is and pasted in my page.

Comment: can you show me your whole jQuery code? add it to your question

Comment: Hey I am not able to add the code. It shows to much of code error.
This is the site Link: http://juzzstaging.com/eha/ . can you please have a look.

Comment: the code looks fine, but try defining the click event as `$(document).on('click','.bullet',function(){`

Comment: you're welcome again ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add add to li when scroll to section and given background color to that class

Comment: When giving an answer, it's best not to guess or make assumptions. If possible, provide a working example of code that will do what the OP is asking for.